# long running query alternating states

Tags: mysql

I have a long running query (about 3 minutes) that upon query execution, alternates states between "sending data" and "writing to net". Why does it alternate states like that and if it's an internal request within the network how come it takes 1 minute to accomplish this for 50k rows?

Comment: Where are you running this query? Delay depends on the operations involved to complete the request.

Comment: It's a pretty powerful machine, 16 cores. The web server is internal and they communicate over LAN with private IPs.